# Knockout.js - Updating a textbox when a dropdown has changed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying update a textbox when I change the value of a select.

Now, I know this is fairly simple however I'm not looking to update the textbox with easy to get data.

Here's what I can do so far:

- Catch the change event
- Get the ID from the Select dropdown

Here's what I want to do:

- Use the selected ID to return a property value from inside an array of objects inside my viewmodel. However, the ID does not match the array index (i.e. the selected ID may be "43" but the index is 0).

Not much point in posting my Knockout code as it's fairly basic so instead I'll post my VM structure.

```
ViewModel
--> Property1
--> Property2
--> Array
    --> Object[0]
        --> "Property to match with the selected ID"
        --> "Property that I want to return"
    --> Object[1]
```

Not really sure how much sense this is making, hope it makes some.

Any other info can be provided.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

VM

```
var PurchaseOrderViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.UpdateCurrency = function (data, event) {
        //
    }
    self.UpdateSupplierContactDetails = function (data, event) {
        //
    }

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var viewModel = new PurchaseOrderViewModel(@Html.Raw(jsonString));

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

**EDIT #2**

Managed to get a working solution, in case anyone else has issues here is how I worked around it.

```
var contact = ko.unwrap(ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.AllSupplierContacts(),
    function (item) {
        return ko.unwrap(item.Id) === newID;
    }).BusinessTelephoneNumber);
```

Comment: There's always a point in posting your current code, at the very least because we don't have to write a test fixture from scratch just to have something to work with. Post your code. Make it a (mostly) working example, viewmodel, data, view, initialization and everything.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yeah, probably poorly worded. What I meant by that is that it's essentially boilerplate as of now and I'm trying to expand it with this first function. Will edit the OP with source.

Answer (score 1):

This answer has two parts: the code I think you're looking for (1), and the code I think you should write (2).

**1. Finding an item that matches an id**

```js
ko.applyBindings(new function() {
  
  this.ids = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
  this.selectedId = ko.observable();
  
  this.items = [
    { key: "A", value: 1 },
    { key: "B", value: 2 },
    { key: "C", value: 3 },
  ];
  this.selectedValue = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var selectedId = this.selectedId();
    
    // Find the object in items of which the property
    // `key` matches the `selectedId` and return it
    var match = this.items.find(function(item) {
      return item.key === selectedId;
    });
    
    return match ? match.value : "No item found";
  }, this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: ids, value: selectedId"></select>

<div>
  Your selected value: <strong data-bind="text: selectedValue"></strong>
</div>
```

**2. Binding the *actual elements* to the select:**

Knockout's `options` binding does many things out of the box. You probably don't need to store `ids` and `items` separately. By telling the binding which property it should render in the dropdown (`optionsText`), and which to store as a value (`optionsValue`), you'll need a lot less code to do the same thing:

```js
ko.applyBindings(new function() {
  
  this.items = [
    { key: "A", value: 1 },
    { key: "B", value: 2 },
    { key: "C", value: 3 },
    { key: "D", value: 4 }
  ];
  
  this.selectedValue = ko.observable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: items,
                   optionsText: 'key',
                   optionsValue: 'value',
                   value: selectedValue"></select>

<div>
  Your selected value: <strong data-bind="text: selectedValue"></strong>
</div>
```

Comment: `new function()`??

Comment: That's just a shorthand for `var ViewModel = function() { /* ... */ }; var vm = new ViewModel();`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I managed to solve this issue, I had no idea ko.utils.arrayFirst existed!

Comment: It's the `ko.utils` equivalent of `Array.prototype.find` and probably safer to use in terms of browser support. The approach remains the same though: you write a `test` method that holds the logic of which property name to check for the required value.

Comment: Upvoted, but there are two things I'd do differently. A) The `optionsValue` binding in the second code sample is superfluous, imho. I'd always rather store the entire item instead of only part of it, that makes things much easier to work with. B) As the OP points out, `ko.utils.arrayFirst` is the better fit for the situation in the first code sample. I'd also not return the string `"No item found"` when nothing is found, but `undefined` instead. Makes working with the viewmodel easier as well. These things are better solved in the view anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, @Tomalak. In my opinion, stack overflow answers do not have to be copy-pasteable code but should show solution directions. My answer aimed to: A) show a computed `Array.prototype.find` method. What `find` does internally is very easy to look up and polyfill/import/rewrite. Then, B) show that the _better knockout approach_ would be to bind to the _actual data_. Showing both `optionsText` and `optionsValue` gives a complete example, it's up to the OP to determine what they want to do in their view. (not what the question was about and no clear direction to take)

Comment: A) I realize that, but `fin‌​d` can return more than one item, which would break things in this context. `return ko.utils.arrayFirst‌​(...)` not only results in clearer and shorter code, it also produces a result that is consistent with viewmodel semantics (`selectedValue` = singular) B) Most people new to knockout are surprised that they don't have to work with string values in dropdowns, but can bind to entire object instances instead. Using `optionsValue` makes that fact difficult to recognize and leads to "how can I lookup this ID I just selected" questions like this one. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The whole issue of "having to look up an ID in an array" can be side-stepped by not working with IDs at all, but with the array items themselves.

```js
function MyList(params) {
   var self = this;

   // observables
   self.items = ko.observableArray();
   self.selectedItem = ko.observable();

   // init
   ko.mapping.fromJS(params, {}, self);

   // post-init
   self.items.sort(function (a, b) {
       return ko.unwrap(a.key) < ko.unwrap(b.key) ? -1 : 1;
   });
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyList({
    items: [
        { key: "D", id: 4 },
        { key: "A", id: 3 },
        { key: "B", id: 2 },
        { key: "C", id: 1 }
    ]
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="
    optionsCaption: 'Please select...',
    options: items,
    optionsText: 'key',
    value: selectedItem
"></select>

<div data-bind="with: selectedItem">
  Your selected value: <strong data-bind="text: id"></strong>
</div>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: Isn't this answer basically a copy of the approach I recommend in the second part of my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38957151/3297291 ? Did I miss an important difference?

Comment: Approach-wise, yes. I had it in the works while you posted yours. The differences are in the details. I highlighted them in my comment beneath your answer.